# Mui tooltip is hidden inside the container

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, ag-grid

I have a menu created using tooltip inside a ag-grid container.

The menu is sometimes hidden behind the container.

[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2PTo.png)

component used ToolTip.Mui version- V4
Pooperprops used

```
 PopperProps: {
    disablePortal: true
 }
```

The menu should be always visible.

I have tried the below one  from [Position a MUI tooltip inside a container so that it does not overflow outside of the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75422453/position-a-mui-tooltip-inside-a-container-so-that-it-does-not-overflow-outside-o)

but it leads to [Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRF1g.png). The  tooltip is visible outside of the container making the container to be scrollable.

```
const boundingElement = useRef();
[...]
<div
  ref={boundingElement}
>
  <Tooltip
    title="Tooltip Tooltip Tooltip Tooltip Tooltip"
    PopperProps={{
      popperOptions: {
        modifiers: [
          {
             name: "preventOverflow",
             options: {
               boundary: boundingElement.current
             }
          }
        ]
      }
    }}
  >
    <div>Tooltip Hover Div</div>
  </Tooltip>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that bug.  I was the one that wrote the answer you referenced.  I have updated the answer with a fix.  Does the edit help in your case?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75422453/position-a-mui-tooltip-inside-a-container-so-that-it-does-not-overflow-outside-o